# How do I write a three-block context manager in Python?

Tags: python, contextmanager

I have many functions that exploit the context manager pattern:

```
@contextmanager
def f():
    # Do preliminary stuff.
    yield
    # Do final stuff.
```

I use an `ExitStack` to call all of these context managers.

I am considering the pattern:

```
@threeblock_contextmanager
def f():
    # Do preliminary stuff.
    yield
    # Do intermediary stuff.
    yield
    # Do final stuff.
```

I've been looking at [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.2/Lib/contextlib.py) and thought I would modify it in some way.  Is there a nice way to accomplish this?  My other option is to add a method to each class that returns a context manager.  The disadvantage of adding a method is that the intuitive linear view of the code is lost because the intermediary stuff will be in a different method rather than placed between the preliminary and final stuff, which I consider more logical.

---

As requested, more code:

```
def fire(self, cluster_index, obs_count=1.0):
    with ExitStack() as stack:
        for link in self.terminal.out:
            stack.enter_context(
                link.source_firing(cluster_index, obs_count))
        for link in self.terminal.in_:
            stack.enter_context(
                link.target_firing(cluster_index, obs_count))

        # At this point all context managers have been run up until
        # their yield.   They saw a signal that was neither updated at
        # the source nor the target.

        # Update signals.

        # TODO: at this point, the context managers need to send any signals they
        # want to send and yield again.

    # At this point all context managers have been run entirely.
    # On closing, they saw a signal has been updated at both the source
    # and the receiver.

    self.ask_for_reschedule()
```

Comment: Are you actually using these as context managers (with 'with')? Can you explain how you would expect a three-part context manager to work?

Comment: @nneonneo I guess the caller would have to store the context managers in a list.  Call `enter_context` on each of them using an open ExitStack (or similar class).  At some point in the context manager, he would maybe make a call to each context manager to a method, say `middle`.  Finally, the context manager ends and the ExitStack does its usual thing.

Comment: @nneonneo [`ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack)

Comment: I was going to post an answer but I realized I still do not understand at all what you're going to accomplish; if you want to ask for a nice way to do X, then post the actual code, otherwise we have the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Thank you for considering to post an answer.  The code is very long.  I have many classes that inherit from each other and expose many context managers.  These frequently employ a `with super().method(*args, **kwargs):` pattern.  All of these methods are kicked off by a method that I've described in some detail in my other comment.  Is there something in this process that's unclear?

Comment: What "intermediary stuff" might such a context manager do -- can you give a realistic or useful example?

Comment: IMO, what you're describing sounds more like a coroutine than a context manager.

Comment: @martineau: Do you mean just zip a whole bunch of generators and use a for loop over that?

Comment: The yield in context manager is supposed to return a value for the `__enter__` - you could yield a closure with the original contextmanager decorator.