# How do I write a generic subclass generator method in Python

Tags: python, generator

I have the following method structure:

```
def source_firing(self, source_index, delta_pre_out):
    x = super().source_firing(source_index, delta_pre_out)

    # do something A
    yield next(x)
    # do something B
    yield next(x)
    # do something C
```

The idea is to get the superclass to follow along.  Unfortunately, C is not done by the parent class unless I add:

```
    try:
      next(x)
    except StopIteration:
      pass
    else:
      raise Exception
```

Is there a nicer pattern?

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what you're asking here ... Can you try to make it more clear?  What is the problem?  What is C? Could you make a minimal example that we could copy/paste/run/reproduce?

Comment: @mgilson:  It's based on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424980/how-do-i-write-a-three-block-context-manager-in-python

Comment: The idea is to do a sequence of tasks.  The caller is going to update various things as it iterates over the generator.

Comment: C is whatever is done at the parent in place of "do something C"